# Crystal report distributable runtime

Tags: php, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have developed an application in php that exports pdf with crystal reports using COM such as "CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1". It works on my machine that has full crystal report installed. I'm looking to load into another machine.

Do I need to install a full crystal report there? Or is there a runtime only installer, that is without designer? If so, kindly point to where it can be downloaded.

Comment: whats the meaning of this voting down and up? if it makes your day voting it, do as you please.

Answer (score 0):

There is Crystal redistributable , which is part of your Crystal installation disk. Search the disk for "runtime"

Comment: thanks Lan, I found CRRedist2005_x86.msi and CrystalRedist115_x86.msi and installed it on a bare test machine, the script $ObjectFactory= new COM("CrystalReports115.ObjectFactory.1") works, however the $crapp = $ObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalDesignRunTime.Application") fails. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not using COM runtime , so I am not sure , but CrystalDesignRunTime looks like a COM object for the Design time (at least this i what the name says). Runtime will deploy just the client part , so the Design component will be still missing from the machine.

Comment: Through this com, it allows access the report, pass parameter, manipulate data source and export.I have a feeling redist is largely for .net environment as it is found inside the visual studio, and thus missing. There is very little to none documentation on its use unfortunately.

Comment: As far as I remember COM components were in 2-3 dlls. CRXADRT.dll is the one , which should be enough to run a report.

Comment: Lan, exactly thats the library to access the report, not sure it would work by simply registering the dll, never think of it, will give it a try. many thanks :)

Comment: It should work by registering it. Check if it depends by other dlls